# Loading ProgresBar in Webview

Tags: java, android

I have problem.
I do a progressbar in main2activity.
App starts but when the website its loaded the progressbar is not disappear.
And my app crashed.
Please help ! :*
I would like to correct my code because this is the best way to learn where was a mistake.
Thanks!

There is code :

```
    package musial.pzstis.com.pzstiz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

/*
 * Demo of creating an application to open any URL inside the application and clicking on any link from that URl
should not open Native browser but  that URL should open in the same screen.

- Load WebView with progress bar
 */
public class Main2Activity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    WebView myWebView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar7);

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fpzstiz.swiebodzin.pl%2Fzastepstwa%2FPZSTiZ_zastepstwa.pdf");
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        myWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);

    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    // To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

There are LOGS:

```
    02-14 20:43:38.592 20262-20299/musial.pzstis.com.pzstiz E/EGL_emulation: tid 20299: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
02-14 20:43:44.672 20262-20262/musial.pzstis.com.pzstiz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: musial.pzstis.com.pzstiz, PID: 20262
                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at musial.pzstis.com.pzstiz.Main2Activity$myWebClient.onPageFinished(Main2Activity.java:66)
                                                                              at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.onPageFinished(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:531)
                                                                              at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientCallbackHelper$MyHandler.handleMessage(AwContentsClientCallbackHelper.java:188)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
02-14 20:43:44.777 1569-4538/system_process E/EGL_emulation: tid 4538: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you got an null pointer Exception with the progressbar, i would encapsulate every access to the progressbar in this form:

```
if(progressBar == null)
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar7);
if(progressBar)
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Implemented in vour code:

```
public class Main2Activity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

WebView myWebView;
ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar7);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient(this));
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fpzstiz.swiebodzin.pl%2Fzastepstwa%2FPZSTiZ_zastepstwa.pdf");
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    myWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);

}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{

    privat Activity main2ac;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    public myWebClient(Activity handle){
        main2ac = handle;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(progressBar == null)
            progressBar = (ProgressBar)main2ac.findViewById(R.id.progressBar7);
        if(progressBar)
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        if(progressBar == null)
            progressBar = (ProgressBar)main2ac.findViewById(R.id.progressBar7);
        if(progressBar)
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Hmmm can you add this /edit in code?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 1):

Pass progressBar to your custom webview :

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient(progressBar));
```

Change your myWebClient class to this:

```
public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
     private ProgressBar progressBar;

    public myWebClient(ProgressBar progressBar) {
        this.progressBar=progressBar;
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: pass the progressbar in  myWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient(progressBar));

Comment: now when i click button to this activity app stop. There is code from monitor. http://pastebin.com/sfbkdyaf

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: Are you sure you have added a progressbar with the id "progressBar7" in the layout "activity_main_2.xml" ? (Just checking)